# Using DIVs for table: how to alternate row colors with two or more columns

Tags: css, html

I have been very successful at creating a table using DIVs and having the columns alternate colors. However, I'm trying to alternate rows. I know I'm close, but I'm now banging my head against the wall. There is quite of bit of code, so I've created a jsfiddle.net project that holds the code and you can see the results I'm getting.

.[Here's the link jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K6LN9/)

Here's the HTML:

```
<body>
<div>
    <div class="list-table">
        <div class="title top">Membership List</div>
        <div class="heading-row">
            <div class="col-heading-1 col-background">Mbr ID</div>
            <div class="col-heading-2 col-background">Member Name</div>
            <div class="col-heading-3 col-background">Member Email</div>
            <div class="col-heading-4 col-background">Action</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="detail">
            <div class="col-1">1</div>
            <div class="col-2">John Doe</div>
            <div class="col-3">jd@johndoe.com</div>
            <div class="col-4">Delete</div>
            <div class="col-5">Edit</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="detail">
            <div class="col-1">2</div>
            <div class="col-2">John Wayne</div>
            <div class="col-3">jw@jw.com</div>
            <div class="col-4">Delete</div>
            <div class="col-5">Edit</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="detail">
            <div class="col-1">3</div>
            <div class="col-2">Sally Smith</div>
            <div class="col-3">sally@sallysmith.com</div>
            <div class="col-4">Delete</div>
            <div class="col-5">Edit</div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="title bottom">End of data</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.list-table {
width: 800px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.list-table .title {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bolder;
    text-align: center;
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #2AA6FF 0%, #A5F0EF 50%, #2AA6FF 100%);
    /* Mozilla Firefox */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #2AA6FF 0%, #A5F0EF 50%, #2AA6FF 100%);
    /* Opera */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #2AA6FF 0%, #A5F0EF 50%, #2AA6FF 100%);
    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, 2AA6FF),     color-stop(0.5, #A5F0EF), color-stop(1, #2AA6FF));
    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #2AA6FF 0%, #A5F0EF 50%, #2AA6FF 100%);
    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2AA6FF 0%, #A5F0EF 50%, #2AA6FF 100%);
}
.list-table .top {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;    
}
.list-table .bottom {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
.list-table .heading-row {
}
.list-table .heading-row .col-heading-1 {
    width: 10%;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}
.list-table .heading-row .col-heading-2 {
    width: 35%;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}
.list-table .heading-row .col-heading-3 {
    width: 35%;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}
.list-table .heading-row .col-heading-4 {
    width: 20%;
    font-size: small;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}
.list-table .heading-row .col-background {
    /* IE10 Consumer Preview */
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #808080 0%, #D3D3D3 50%, #808080 100%);
    /* Mozilla Firefox */
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #808080 0%, #D3D3D3 50%, #808080 100%);
    /* Opera */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #808080 0%, #D3D3D3 50%, #808080 100%);
    /* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #808080), color-stop(0.5, #D3D3D3), color-stop(1, #808080));
    /* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #808080 0%, #D3D3D3 50%, #808080 100%);
    /* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #808080 0%, #D3D3D3 50%, #808080 100%);
}
.list-table .clear {
    clear: both;
}
.list-table .detail {
    background-color: #eee;
}
.list-table .detail div:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#eee;
}
.list-table .detail div:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#fff;
}
.list-table .detail .col-1 {
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
.list-table .detail .col-2 {
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
}
.list-table .detail .col-3 {
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
}
.list-table .detail .col-4 {
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
.list-table .detail .col-5 {
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Can you describe how you want to have the row colors altered exactly? Every second row having a different color, or having them like a chessboard?

Comment: Irrelevant to your problem, but why not use a real table?  This is tabular data, right?

Comment: oneday - the colors may not be contrasting enough to see. I'm changing alternating columns between white and lightgrey, what I want to do is change alternating rows between white and lightgrey. HaukurHaf - are you saying the only way I can do this is with <table> <tr> <td> <th>, etc tags? Just an FYI, I did do it using a 'real table' and I had so much CSS that I couldn't see the forest because of the trees. From reading/research I've found the use of DIVs is faster and uses less code.

Comment: You can do it with tables or divs or even p, but semantically tables have the right meaning to be used here, div means "nothing, just placing things". Better a table for this case. @Rich_R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is just what you are looking for.

To make things simpler, I have taken all the 'rows' and placed it inside a container div called 'rows'. I have also applied background colors as you wanted as well as keeping alternate colors. I have added margin and padding to make the colors obvious (i kow it doenst look good but its done for illustration purpose).

These are the 2 CSS classes I used:

```
.detail {
    background-color: Gray;
    color: Blue;
    height:20px;
    width:100%;
    padding:25px 0;
}
.rows > div:nth-child(4n) {
    background-color:Orange;
    color: red;
}
```

And I modified (just added a container called row as previously stated) the HTML as such:

```
<div class="rows">
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <div class="detail">
                <div class="col-1">1</div>
                <div class="col-2">John Doe</div>
                <div class="col-3">jd@johndoe.com</div>
                <div class="col-4">Delete</div>
                <div class="col-5">Edit</div>
            </div>
..Other 'detail' classes
</div>
```

You can take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/8bLUH/1/

**The idea is that I have given you the 2 alternate classes named 'detail' *(odd row)* and rows . div:nth-child(4n) *(even row)*. You can apply whatever styling you want on them.**

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Yes! this does work and with some adjustments got it to the way I would like: http://jsfiddle.net/rich_r/8bLUH/2/. I have other suggestions from yourself and miguel-svq that will help since I'm generating the table via php, I also may look at using the row number to set the background-color depending on odd or even row.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking now... well... being a table or divs (but tabular data deserves a table) doesn't really matter for this answer:

Why don't you add a class to mark even/odd rows in the loop that creates the html? (div class="detail" vs div class="detail even"...)

Then in css color them as you want...

```
.even{background-color: #DDDDAA}
.odd{background-color: #BBBBFF}
```

Comment: CSS already has psuedo-selectors for even and odd. So, if you structure your html correctly, you would never need to create classes called even and odd. You should be doing that with the psuedo-selectors.

Comment: Additionally, if you are using the psuedo-selectors then you don't need to specify the class name each time. It becomes extensible. You can add more elements and the styling would be automated. I hope you understand the point.

Comment: And yes, you are right. Using a table in this case does make sense!!

Comment: Yep @Satwik , but pseudo-selectors have limited support, specially in older browsers. If he is developing the backend it's not a big effort to give this additional class to handle all the cases. (I've just read a complain about an anwser not supporting IE7, maybe it affected me too much :D )

Answer (score 1):

This solution isn't perfect, but will give you something to work with.  Add this to the bottom of your styles:

```
.list-table > div:nth-child(4n) {
   color: red;
}
```

This will set the text color of every 4th div to red.  This will look like an alternating row since each "row" in the table has a "clear" div and a "detail" div.

Comment: ...and if you use a table (as you should) selector could be tr:nth-child(2n)

Comment: Phil, thanks for the suggestion, this did turn the 'color' to red for alternating rows, so I thought I'd try with background and that did nothing. miquel-svq is suggesting to use 'real table'. I've been trying the DIV method based on recommendations, but apparently I'm not able to do it. I've got my code for using 'real tables' and I'll put up on jsFiddle.net and we can see the difference.

Comment: I would agree with @miguel-svq that this example looks perfectly suited for real tables.  If you're using real tables I'd recommend using <thead /> <tbody /> and the <tfooter> tags to help separate your styling.  Then doing the style of tbody tr:nth-child(odd) will style only the content you want

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery and it becomes easy:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/K6LN9/4/)

```
$(function(){
    var count = 0;
    var baseColor = true;
    $(".detail > div").each(function(){
        count++;
        if (baseColor){
            $(this).css("background-color", "#BCEAEF");
        }
        if (count > 4){  // 4 is the number of columns - 1
            count = 0;
            if (baseColor){
                baseColor = false;
            }
            else{
                baseColor = true;
            }
        }        
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't see that piece of code + jquery library simpler or easier that choosing the appropiate css selector.

Comment: I do have to agree with Miguel-svq on this. I am generating the table with PHP and can easily determine if the MySQL row is odd or even and hen select the color of the row based on that.